# ABIs [armeabi, mips, mips64, riscv64] are not supported for platform

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle

Обновил студию (2023.1.1) и AGP (8.2), больше ничего не менял.
На предыдущих версиях проблем не было.
Теперь проект не собирается по причине:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: [CXX1201]
  ABIs [armeabi, mips, mips64, riscv64] are not supported for platform.
  Supported ABIs are [arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64].
```

Где он их нашёл... в проекте нигде никакие ABIs не заданы, кроме:

```
   splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

Прописывать фильтры пробовал - выхлоп тот же

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    }
```

Comment: Может кто-то из зависимостей тянет? armeabi, mips уже несколько лет как не поддерживаются NDK. Ошибку или NDK или AGP выдает, попробуйте на AGP 8.1 откатиться, может какой новый check добавили в 8.2

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, на предыдущей версии AGP проблем нет, я написал об этом. Не понимаю как зависимости могут влиять на конфигурацию NDK и почему тогда `abiFilters` не отметает ненужное? А как это вообще выяснить что там тянут в натив зависимости?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось проблема в `AbiSplit` - нужно вызвать `reset()` для удаления предустановленного фильтра (с чего вдруг решили вернуть эти архитектуры в фильтр по-умолчанию - загадка):

```
   splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```